# How could I get this JavaScript drop down to work on specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically what this script does is when a user right clicks anywhere on the webpage, it displays a custom drop down however im interested in making this so that it only shows the custom right click menu on a specific object or div.  not so that appears anywhere on the screen. Thankyou for any suggestions or demos.

**The Script**

```
<script>
$(document).bind("contextmenu", function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
$(".custom-menu").finish().toggle(100).
css({
    top: event.pageY + "px",
    left: event.pageX + "px"
});
});
$(document).bind("mousedown", function (e) {
if (!$(e.target).parents(".custom-menu").length > 0) {
$(".custom-menu").hide(100);
}
});
$(".custom-menu li").click(function(){

    // This is the triggered action name
    switch($(this).attr("data-action")) {

    // A case for each action. Your actions here
    case "first": alert("first"); break;
    case "second": alert("second"); break;
    case "third": alert("third"); break;
    }


    $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
   });
  </script>
```

**Body**

```
<ul class='custom-menu'>
<li data-action="first">First thing</li>
<li data-action="second">Second thing</li>
<li data-action="third">Third thing</li>
</ul>
Right click me
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use on with a context

```js
$(document).on("contextmenu", ".rc", function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
$(".custom-menu").finish().toggle(100).
css({
    top: event.pageY + "px",
    left: event.pageX + "px"
});
});
$(document).bind("mousedown", function (e) {
if (!$(e.target).parents(".custom-menu").length > 0) {
$(".custom-menu").hide(100);
}
});
$(".custom-menu li").click(function(){

    // This is the triggered action name
    switch($(this).attr("data-action")) {

    // A case for each action. Your actions here
    case "first": alert("first"); break;
    case "second": alert("second"); break;
    case "third": alert("third"); break;
    }


    $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
   });
```

```css
.custom-menu{
   display:none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='custom-menu'>
<li data-action="first">First thing</li>
<li data-action="second">Second thing</li>
<li data-action="third">Third thing</li>
</ul>
<span class="rc">Here</span>
<span>Nope</span>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, fixed the issue and thank you again for the support and applying you demo to the question

Answer (score 1):

Replace first `$(document)` with `$(".click_me")`

HTML:

```
<ul class='custom-menu'>
    <li data-action="first">First thing</li>
     <li data-action="second">Second thing</li>
    <li data-action="third">Third thing</li>
</ul>
<span class="click_me">Right click me</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Crete a div and id it as click & place your content **Right click me** in the div! Like this:-

```
<div id="click">Right click me</div>
```

Instead of `$(document).bind` use `$("#click").bind`

Comment: @Lewis Tyler Hope it Helps!